# How to mark unused component in Orcad?

Tags: orcad

How to mark unused components in Orcad?

Often there are resistors/capacitors/other-components that you don't want to be assembled in the final product, but you wish to leave them in the schema in order to apply different features of the product at other times.

What kind of field should I add to the component and how to do that technically?

Comment: It sounds like you want to have the components in the schematic and corresponding pads in the layout, but not populate them during the assembly, right?  Also, which version of OrCAD have you got?

Comment: @NickAlexeev: Correct! I have Orcad 16.5

Comment: Give them a value of NF (= not fitted) and if you have value options in the design make a table using text and list version 1's values, version 2 etc..

Comment: I solved a similar problem in "CircuitLab" by Grounding one leg of each unused component.

Comment: @Andyaka - I use "DNP" (do not place/populate) for the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add a property to every component: 'displayed value.' When this is set to 'DNP,' it shows up on the schematic that way. Also, the BOM-generator  can leave out components for costing and purchasing. (I use Design Spark, but I believe Orcad could do this, too.)